# Spring-Boot application is failing to start due to Liquibase issue on Oracle in StandardLockService

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, liquibase, rds

Running spring-boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and using liquibase 3.6.3 on Oracle 12.1.0.2.v15, I get exception on startup:

> Did not update change log lock correctly.\n\n 0 rows were updated instead of the expected 1 row using executor oracle  there are 0 rows in the table

This:

- https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/lockservice/StandardLockService.java#L334

Investigating, I suspect it might be related to some missing right of my user as it works fine on a database created with AWS RDS 12.1.0.2.v15 but not on the on premise database.

The only noticeable difference is that the user for on premise has no access to v$parameter so I get:

> Could not set check compatibility mode on OracleDatabase, assuming not running in any sort of compatibility mode: Cannot read from v$parameter: ..

Has anybody an idea ?

Can it be related to autocommit default value ?

Any link to requirements for Oracle user when using liquibase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue ended up being an Oracle user misconfiguration by DBA, he had no privileges on tablespace.

But this issue didn't appear in logs.

Once I removed liquibase context:

> spring.liquibase.contexts

The issue appeared clearly:

> ORA-01950 : no privileges on tablespace ....